# World map chart will not load

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, world-map

Hi I would like to make a world map with all the countries in it and eventually let it keep track from where people made a transaction. It will not even show up. I was wondering what i am doing wrong here...

```js
<td height="24"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geochart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGeo);

var CPI score = 0;

 var counts = {};
 var xmlURL = "https://connect.compliancewise.nl/compliancewise/sheetViewExportXML.action?metaData.siteID=723&metaData.sheetId=4594&metaData.sheetViewID=24401&metaData.isheetExportType=xml";
  
 var xml;
    $j.ajax({
        url:xmlURL,
        dataType:"xml",
  beforeSend: function(){
   $j('#loader').show();
  },
        success: function(data){
            xml = data;
   $j('#loader').hide();
            createGeochart();
        }
    });
 
 
function createGeochart(){
console.log("gelukt");
        var columns = {};
  var columnNames = [];
        var xmlColumns = $j('head', xml);
        xmlColumns.find('headColumn').each(function(){
            var columnName = $j(this).find('columnValue').text();
            var columnID = $j(this).attr('columnid');
   columnNames.push(columnName);
            columns[columnName] = columnID;
        });
        
        var xmlData = $j('data', xml);
rawDataGeo= [
          ['Country',   'CPI score'],
["Bhutan",1],                           
["Democratic Republic of the Congo",1], 
["Liechtenstein",1],                    
["Maldives",1],                         
["Sudan",1],                            
["Zimbabwe",1],                         
["Mauritania",1],                       
["Mozambique",1],                       
["Nigeria",1],                          
["Swaziland",1],                        
["Tanzania",1],                         
["Iraq",1],                             
["Guyana",1],                           
["Namibia",1],                          
["Senegal",1],                          
["Turkmenistan",1],                     
["Afghanistan",1],                      
["Andorra",1],                          
["Fiji",1],                             
["Gabon",1],                            
["Uzbekistan",1],                       
["Cameroon",1],                         
["Cuba",1],                             
["Faroe Islands",1],                    
["El Salvador",1],                      
["Caribbean",1],                        
["Ethiopia",1],                         
["Mongolia",1],                         
["Puerto Rico",1],                      
["Samoa",1],                            
["Myanmar",1],                          
["Nicaragua",1],                        
["Seychelles",1],                       
["Tajikistan",1],                       
["Dominican Republic",1],               
["Guinea",1],                           
["Barbados",1],                         
["CI",1],                               
["Laos",1],                             
["Libya",1],                            
["Panama",1],                           
["Bahrain",1],                          
["Benin",1],                            
["Ghana",1],                            
["Haiti",1],                            
["Montenegro",1],                       
["Somalia",1],                          
["Syria",1],                            
["Ecuador",1],                          
["Honduras",1],                         
["Madagascar",1],                       
["Papua New Guinea",1],                 
["Tunisia",1],                          
["Angola",1],                           
["Botswana",1],                         
["Cyprus",1],                           
["Algeria",1],                          
["Bahamas",1],                          
["New Caledonia",1],                    
["Uganda",1],                           
["Yemen",1],                            
["Zambia",2],                           
["Antarctica",2],                       
["Paraguay",2],                         
["Jamaica",2],                          
["Palestine",2],                        
["Bolivia",2],                          
["Bosnia and Herzegovina",2],           
["Vietnam",2],                          
["Kenya",2],                            
["Luxembourg",2],                       
["Niger",2],                            
["Kuwait",2],                           
["Hawaii",2],                           
["Scotland",2],                         
["Cambodia",2],                         
["Uruguay",2],                          
["Kyrgyzstan",2],                       
["Saudi Arabia",2],                     
["Indonesia",2],                        
["Azerbaijan",2],                       
["United Arab Emirates",2],             
["Mauritius",2],                        
["Morocco",2],                          
["Albania",3],                          
["South Korea",3],                      
["Kazakhstan",3],                       
["Macedonia",3],                        
["Venezuela",3],                        
["Taiwan",3],                           
["Qatar",3],                            
["Jordan",3],                           
["Iceland",3],                          
["Guatemala",3],                        
["Costa Rica",3],                       
["Hong Kong",3],                        
["San Marino",3],                       
["Colombia",4],                         
["Moldova",4],                          
["Armenia",4],                          
["Malta",4],                            
["Nepal",5],                            
["Lebanon",5],                          
["Malaysia",5],                         
["Serbia",5],                           
["Peru",5],                             
["Trinidad and Tobago",5],              
["Lithuania",5],                        
["Estonia",6],                          
["Georgia",6],                          
["Iran",7],                             
["Chile",7],                            
["Latvia",7],                           
["Thailand",7],                         
["Egypt",7],                            
["Slovenia",8],                         
["Mexico",8],                           
["Belarus",8],                          
["Slovakia",9],                         
["Sri Lanka",9],                        
["Croatia",9],                          
["Philippines",9],                      
["Bangladesh",10],                      
["Turkey",10],                          
["Romania",13],                         
["Italy",14],                           
["South Africa",15],                    
["Hungary",15],                         
["Pakistan",16],                        
["Portugal",16],                        
["Ukraine",19],                         
["Greece",19],                          
["Oman",19],                            
["Argentina",19],                       
["Singapore",20],                       
["Bulgaria",20],                        
["Japan",25],                           
["Czech Republic ",26],                 
["Ireland",26],                         
["China",27],                           
["Finland",32],                         
["Brazil",33],                          
["Norway",34],                          
["Austria",35],                         
["Denmark",40],                         
["Belgium",41],                         
["New Zealand",42],                     
["Spain",43],                           
["Switzerland",57],                     
["Russia",62],                          
["Poland",65],                          
["Israel",73],                          
["Sweden",91],                          
["Netherlands",118],                    
["France",119],                         
["Australia",158],                      
["Canada",206],                         
["India",234],                          
["Germany",308],                        
["United Kingdom",614],                 
["United States",983]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                     ];
  
xmlData.find('item').each(function(){
  var col;
  var row;
            $j(this).find('column').each(function(){
                var colID = $j(this).attr("columnid");         
    if(colID == columns["CPI score"]){
     var value = $j(this).find('displayData').text();
     col = rawDataGeo[0].indexOf(value);
    }
    else{
     var date = $j(this).find('displayData').text();
     var res = date.split("/");
     row = parseInt(res[1]);
    }
            })
  rawDataGeo[row][col]++;
        })

        drawGeo(rawDataGeo);
    }  
 
function drawGeo(rawDataGeo) {

        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawDataGeo);

var options = {
        
         chartArea:{width:'100%',height:'100%'},
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);   
}
    </script>
      <div id="regions_div" style="width: 100%;">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
```

Any help/feedback is welcome!

Comment: Yes indeed i use jquery

Comment: if you could share the jquery version / url and a sample of the xml data, we could get a demo running...